# Как правильно организовать двустороннюю связь между окнами С# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, iframe

Суть: есть 2 веб-формы, в которых нужно организовать связь следующего типа, чтобы по клику кнопки с первой веб-формы, открывалась панель `<asp:Panel>` со второй веб-формы.

На данный момент клик по кнопке просто переносит меня на новую страницу

```
btnRUSC.OnClientClick = "window.open('RUSCOtdelka.aspx'); return false;";
```

Т.е. чтобы я нажимал на кнопку, по нажатию этой кнопки у меня открывалась панель, которая берется из второй веб-формы, там я производил какие-то действия и в случае необходимости закрывал эту панель.

Слышал что подобную задачу можно выполнить с помощью `<iframe>`

Например: `<iframe id ="ifrRUscOtdelka" runat="server" src="RUscOtdelka.aspx.cs"></iframe>`

Но это ведь не совсем правильно, я полагаю. мне ведь необходимо загрузить панель в айфрейме, а не просто новую страницу. Могу ли я эту панель на второй веб-форме поместить в `iframe` и этот `iframe` вызвать уже по клику на первой веб-форме?

Также отмечу, что в форме присутствуют различные параметры, которые будут необходимы для связи этой панели с веб-формой (например возьмём дату). Как это реализовать корректно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не фронтендер конечно, но может есть возможность вынести эту панель как отдельный control, который будет подтягиваться в обе формы. C web формами не работал, но в WPF это можно сделать по типу
`<extcontrols:SaveCancelControl Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"/>`,
где SaveCancelControl отдельно существующий.